# 2 ways to vote that something belongs on SuperUser

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

There are 2 close vote options that seem to say that a question belongs on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow. (I'm not sure what the options are on other SE sites.)

> Closing > Off-Topic > "Questions about general computing hardware and software..."

and

> Closing > Off-topic > Migration > belongs on superuser.com

What's the difference? Why do we have both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one only hints at the question possibly being suitable for Super User. At most it tells the OP to look into that site and see if it's a better fit for the question asked.

The second one however is a direct vote to migrate. If all votes are of the migration kind, the question will end up being migrated to the target site. This won't happen for the first option.

Why have both? If you're not 100% sure that a question is a perfect fit for a target site, you should not vote for migration. I often have an idea it might be a potential fit for a site, but I might not be certain. In that case it's better not to explicitly vote to migrate.

Additionally, a question's subject matter might be a better fit for a specific site, but it might be a poor question. Voting to migrate crap is also something to avoid, so once again, the first option would be a better one.

Comment: Okay, that tells me what the difference is. Do you know why we have both? Is there a justification, or a historical reason, or something of the sort?

Comment: The "don't migrate crap" reason seems a bit strange. On-topic crap gets a "unclear/describe the specific problem/minimal understanding" vote. Off-topic non-crap gets a "go over there" vote. It seems odd that off-topic crap would get a "go over there, but we're not going to put it there for you" instead of a "go over there, and also fix these problems". I suppose this might be something to bring up in a multiple-close-reasons feature request.

Comment: The point is, I don't necessarily *know*, @user2357112. If I'm active on Stack Overflow, I know what a good SO question looks like. Heck, I know what a mediocre but still acceptable question looks like. I don't necessarily know what Super User expects though. Product recommendations are discouraged on SO, but maybe asking for the best video editor for use with YouTube is allowed on SU - perhaps even encouraged, or already asked and answered! Rather than sending the question over "raw", it's more practical to direct the asker to the documentation... And the site's own dup-searching "ask" page.